# How to include appropriate JavaScript file's version (minified vs. raw)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, minify

I am developing a webapp (if it matters, I use `npm` and `bower`). My HTML file includes `angular.js`. Now, I want that my production-version of the webapp uses the minified version `angular.min.js`.

Considering I do want two versions of my webapp:

- A "raw" version which includes `angular.js`
- A "production" version which includes `angular.min.js`

How is it traditionally done given that I want to maintain a single version of `index.html`?

Comment: You should look at `grunt` or `gulp`. It will help you to export all your files to a *production* environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted for `sed` invoked in a `Makefile`:

```
$(RELEASE_DIR)/index.html: $(PUBLIC_DIR)/index.html | $(RELEASE_DIR)/
    $(SED) 's/\.js/.min.js/g' $< > $@

$(RELEASE_DIR)/:
    $(MKDIR) --parents $@
```

I am accepting my own answer because it was simpler to use `sed` rather than using yet another dependency (I already had a `Makefile`).

Answer (score 1):

You can either do it manually or you can use [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)

They will help you to get your files ready for the production environment.

[This tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/) was a big help when I started with gulp.

Comment: This is interesting, thanks; I don't know why I did not encounter this yet. I'll look into it.

Comment: This will help you to concatenate all your js files together and minimized them. Same for css or sass files. There is a lot of possibiliies. Bonne découverte !

Comment: Merci ! I just found [`replace`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace) that could address my need without having to use another tool.